# Sharing Set Experience Site works for one custom object but not for the other custom object

Tags: customer-community, digital-experience, sharing-sets

Hope you can help. New to communities.

- I have 2 custom objects added to the Sharing Set for `Cloned Customer Community User Profile` to view on the Experience site. `Vacation` and `Trending Destinations`.
- The profile has Read access for both objects and all fields.
- The `Vacation` has a lookup to `Contact`, and
- the `Trending Destinations lookup to` Account`.

(my understanding is that lookup to account or contact is required
for custom objects?)

When the Customer community user logs in, it sees the `Vacation` tab & all its records with details but ...

- only sees the `Trending Destination` **tab**, instead of the list of destinations and the record details.
- My guess is that's the mapping on the latter object.

Experience
Site, Sharing Set screenshots[image]

Comment: Check that profile has access to the lookup field to Account on `Trending Destinations` and has R access to Account and that the Account on the Trending Destinations is in fact the same Account as the experience `User.Account`

Comment: "my understanding is that lookup to account or contact is required for custom objects" - why do you say that? Only if the sharing you want should be based on matching the user's contact or account...

Comment: figured it out, thank you!